# how to replace h1 entry title with h2 in category pages only

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, title, get-template-part

This is the function im using:

```
function change_title_h1_h2( $title, $id = null ) {

    return '<h2>'.$title.'</h2>';
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title_h1_h2', 10, 2 );
```

Is there any way to just target the title of the posts in the category pages?

thx!

Comment: `the_title` has there parameters, `the_title( string $before = '', string $after = '', bool $echo = true )`, they are responsible for the wrapping of the content, you can change them there. Unfortunately there is no filter for manipulating the output with the tags, only the value itself

Comment: thx for the answer